# Chatbot that dynamically selects between database or PDF based on user input

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, openai-api, azure-ai, azure-ai-search

I have developed two separate chatbots: one that searches data from my database and another that searches from PDF documents. Now, I want to create a unified chatbot that intelligently decides where to search based on the user's input.

Could someone please suggest approaches or algorithms for implementing this decision-making functionality in the chatbot?

As per example:

`User Question --> Do some analysis --> (Search from PDF OR Search from DB) --> Provide output.`

Comment: Perhaps run both and score the results somehow, and present the "best" result.  After all surely the "do some analysis" is essentially that?

Comment: Yes, but it can double the time if I do search for both. I mean retrieval time for the actual user will be increased in that case.

Comment: If that time is too long, that information and your time constraints should perhaps be in the answer, but you have to ask yourself what are the criteria by which one will be selected over the other if not the quality of the result?